# What are some appropriate uses of readability tests?

Tags: style, metrics

Do you use readability metrics (such as [Gunning fog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunning_fog_index) or [Flesch-Kincaid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_test)) as you're working on a piece?

If so, how do you use them, and what benefit do you get from using them?

Answer (score 4):

I don't tend to use them while working on a piece -- among other things, one of my biggest rules is to **not** think about such things in first draft.  Afterwards, though, especially as I was first learning to write well, the scores helped because I tend to over-write.  Getting a FK score of 16th "grade" or so is a hulluva good reminder to ease off.